# Is there a way to grant permission to run scripts in a BUILD AGENT's script console to non-admins?

Tags: jenkins

Today I realized that I cannot (or I don't know how to) grant permissions to run scripts in some build agent's script console to non-admin users in Jenkins.

The plugin home page states that since Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin V1.5 it is no longer possible to grant the `RunScripts` permission to non-admin users: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console

While I can clearly understand that running scripts in the Jenkins master's script console has to require admin permissions I'd like to have the possibility to grant access to the build agent script console to non-admins.

Maybe somebody knows how to do that or can explain why this would/should not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "collaborative folder". For example, I want the group "project" to have access on the folder, and group project(so all members of this group) can modify the files.

```
mkdir /projectfolder
groupadd project
chmod 2770 /projectfolder
```

Comment: To be honest I don't really get how this relates to my question. Are you talking about the 'cloudbees folder plugin'. How does it relate to the script console permissions?